# Draft documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, database-design

Suppose I have a Mongo collection and a web application to view the collection in the Internet. When I edit the collection (i.e. add, delete, and update the documents) my changes are *instantly* available in the Internet.

Now I would like to save all my changes as a *draft* and when I want to make it available I will publish the draft *explicitly*.

The trivial implementation is to add a new *draft* collection. I edit only this *draft* collection and when I press a *publish* button the *draft* collection is copied to the original collection.

So far so good, but this solution is not scalable since the time of the copy is a function of the collection size. Would you suggest another solution ?

Comment: the proposed trivial implementation would be wrong functionally speaking.  it would require copying over entire collection in order to expose a single document - wouldn't trivial be to copy just the finished draft document into production collection?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky User may add, remove and update _several_ draft documents before publishing them all. I am afraid the blog  was a poor example so I will remove it from the question.

Comment: Still, why not have a "draft" field in documents? You'd flip that bit when you wanted to activate them?

Comment: @WiredPrairie See my comment to Асин answer

Comment: this works for multiple drafts by multiple people even. each document can be either published or unpublished.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I concur. The "draft" field does work for multiple documents. It does not work for document removal though. See the comments to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a field in each document that's a draft that's set if the document is a draft.  Something like:

```
title:"FooBar blah blah",
draft:true
```

When the button is clicked to publish the post you only need to update a single document - that post's document to either change draft to false or `$unset` it.  Your queries which choose which documents to display must be checking for `draft:{$ne:true}` - note that this will match both documents which have draft set to false and documents which don't have the field `draft` at all. This allows you to leave the current documents alone and not need to update them all to have this field.

Comment: Thank you.  Does the `draft` flag work if a document is removed ? Please note I am not talking about a _single_ draft document. User may add, remove and update _several_ documents before publishing. Besides, it probably makes sense to keep _two separate_ collections for draft and published documents. The draft can be optimized for single user read/write and published for highly concurrent read-only.

Comment: @Michael - I don't follow -- do you understand how Mongo uses memory and uses locks? There's quite a lot of information available: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ Having two collections isn't going to help. Having multiple databases may help with locking a little, but seems like a premature and like unnecessary optimization.

Comment: if by removed you mean make it a draft removal then it doesn't really make sense - why would you mark something removed before it should actually be removed?  Even then you can do that with having a draft field and published field.  Or by using version numbers and draft field and consider the highest version with draft:false to be published?    In any case, it makes *no* sense to use two collections and doing heavy renaming as that would be *significantly* less efficient than updating single documents.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I agree that two separate databases may premature and probably unnecessary optimization. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky About removal: user can remove several documents from the collections. After removal he won't see the removed documents but they are still available on the Internet. They won't be available only when  user publishes the collection.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thank you. The "two flag solution" will work and it is much better than having two collections. Now I wonder what if I need more than just one "draft" version. I will post another question about it soon.